# Android mediaPlayer seekTo not working when paused

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

The `seekTo()` method works well when `mediaPlayer` is playing. If `mediaPlayer` is paused, when I seek to a position and call `start()`, it just start playing where it paused.

My code is as following, in the logcat, I can see it seeking.

```
@Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(player == null || player.mediaPlayer == null){
            return;
        }
        Log.e("player status", "status is " + PlayerStatusCache.playerStatus);

        if(durationProgress < player.mediaPlayer.getDuration()){
            player.mediaPlayer.seekTo(durationProgress);
            Log.e("player", "seeking");
        } else {
            player.mediaPlayer.seekTo(player.mediaPlayer.getDuration() - 1000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons on some devices : `SystemClock.sleep(200)` is necessary because `onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer arg0)` is called too soon by the player BEFORE seekTo is really completed.

```
 mMediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSeekComplete() current pos : " + arg0.getCurrentPosition());
            SystemClock.sleep(200);
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(mCurrentPos);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e){
        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
```